# how to use jquery $.post posting on the same page rather than another?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my jquery $.post

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form[name=frmedit]").submit(function() {

            $.post('index.php',
            {
                dealname: $("[name=dealname]").val(),
                startdate: $("[name=startdate]").val()
            },

            function(data)
            {
                if(data.success)
                {
                    location.href = data.redirect;
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#colright #error").html(data.message);
                }
            }, 'json');


            return false;
        });
    });
```

the php part is on the same page

```
if(isset($_POST['btnNext']) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)) 
{ //run query to save data }
```

so my question is can i have all this on one page? 
i also have another question

where i have

```
 $("form[name=frmedit]").submit
```

how can i put the name of the button btnNext in that rather than just .submit? 
the reason why i want to use all this on one page is because when a submit is done i want to check
if a thumbnail uploaded is greather than 0 being that it exists, like i was normally doing.

thanks

Comment: add more info, what u want is to post information or thumbnail in place of form after its submitted.

Comment: why do you want to post to the same page , you can do jquery' ajax and do a partial update of pages.

Comment: data.redirect is a new page right ??

Comment: what i'm trying to do is check in the db if the dealname and the startdate entered does not already exist before the form is submited. the reason why i want it on the same page is because i have parameters like thepage.php?action=new or  thepage.php?action=edit&id=1 and these are hardcoded into the page. in manywords i have like 5 pages into one for me its a form of organization. do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

if your ajax succeeds , then return true so that it will do form submit otherwise do a false, it won't do a form submit

```
function(data)
                {
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        return true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#colright #error").html(data.message);
                        return false
                    }
                }, 'json');


                return false;
```